# Passing value to pointer parameters in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing

In the following code, why does the swap function work in two ways, by passing values as swap(x,y) and swap(&x, &y).

```
int main(){

   int x, y;

   cout << "Enter the values of x and y: ";
   cin >> x >> y;

   swap(x, y);

   cout << "\nSwapped values are, x: " << x << " & y: " << y <<"\n";

   return 0;

}

void swap(int *a, int *b){

   int s;
   s = *a;
   *a = *b;
   *b = s;

}
```

Comment: avoid the `using namespace std;` statement and you will not run into those pitfalls.

Comment: Always post your [MCVE]. You have `using namespace std` but did not show it here. Neglecting to include crucial details wastes our time!!

Comment: Edit in your `using namespace std` and `#include`s, please.

Comment: Your function should be called ::swap(&ax, &y).

Comment: ::swap(&x, &y) of course...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the explanation to the other answer, on why `std::swap` is called:

When you `swap(x, y)`, the compiler tries to look for a `swap` overload to call.  Assuming you had written `using std::swap;` or `using namespace std;`, the namespaces the compiler is allowed to look would be global and `std`.

The prototype `void swap(int, int)` is expected but the compiler is open to options -- functions with same name, same count of parameters but different parameter types that need coercion are OK too -- when looking for a viable overload; after enumerating them, it would choose the closest match.

The one that you've implemented, in the global namespace, is of type

```
void swap(int*, int*);
```

but the one given by the [standard library header `<utility>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) is a function template

```
namespace std {
    template <typename T>
    void swap(T&, T&);
}
```

This overload becomes `void swap(int&, int&)` since `T = int`. Now this is an identity match (no type coercion required) and hence *wins* the overload resolution.

Had you not written `using std::swap;` or `using namespace std;`, then the only possible overload available to the compiler would have been yours, to which you'd have gotten an error saying the argument types mismatch. Fixing it would be fixing the calling code to pass `int*` (address of those variables are of type pointer to `int`) and not `int`:

```
swap(&x, &y);
```

Answer (score 7):

you call `std::swap` when you write `swap(x, y);`

---

In your example, even if you write the `swap(&x, &y);` you will only get compile error unless you declare `void swap(int*,int*);` before `main`.

And `std::swap` can not help on this because it cannot convert rvalue `int*` to `int*&`. (even if it can do this, it will not swap the value of `x` and `y`)

---

Comment: This is just a true statement that doesn't help. To make a helpful answer, you should explain what `std::swap` is, why it is called, and how to fix the problem.

Comment: @anatolyg that is not what the OP ask, if OP have trouble in that, ask another question or look at some reference (or ask in comment). I'll not add more detail until OP request (and related to *this* question).

Comment: maybe OP just forgot the `std::swap`, who knows?

Answer (score 2):

When you call the version swap(x,y) it actually calls the standad library function template "template  void swap (T& a, T& b)"
, declared in "algorithm" header file.